# Internet Explorer works very slowly executing JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, raphael

There is a [page](http://www.inowweb.net/dan/) that uses PHP to fetch search results from Google Search API and then it puts the results on the page some funny way in a circle. The code may look crappy but seems that it works more or less fine in Firefox. When you enter a search query and click submit button or Next/Previous links, it fills the wheel with results. The problem is its work in IE. It works there very slowly and then it doesn't clear the wheel before filling in new data, but puts it over that. My friend asked me to help him with this code. Please give me a piece of advice how I can fix it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Well, for starters, what have you tried so far, what JS framework is this site using (if any), what is the method to fetch the results, etc? In other words, please give us specific information about the internals - otherwise the question sounds like "please debug this for me".

Comment: IE has always had a slower javascript engine. There may not be a lot you can do to increase its speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raphael runs very slowly under IE [documented here](http://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs/browse_thread/thread/b1fff950542eb7ba?pli=1).

As I understand it, VML itself in IE is fast enough, but the Raphael layer has some inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/), which renders vector in VML/SVG (depending on browser).  IE8 has degraded support for VML,  unfortunately, and I hear it's also quite a bit slower than IE7.  BTW, in IE7 it's kinda funny looking.

In terms of Raphael, it may be something as simple as resetting some context, I'm not sure.  I've looked at Raphael before, but never used it.